# Angular 4 Chaining Observables is not causing an update in the GUI when the model changes

Tags: javascript, angular

Angular 4 Chaining Observable's is not causing an update in the DOM when the model changes. The model is an array of objects called users. When favoriteThisUser is called this works correctly and calls the refresh method. This method does not update the DOM but does return the correct results from geosearch.  Can someone explain to me why this is the case?

```
refresh() {
    this.usersService.geosearch(this.usersService.user).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log('!!!USESR!!!', data);
        this.users = data;
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }

  favoriteThisUser(id: string) {
    this.usersService.favorite(id).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log('SUCCESS!!!', data);
        this.refresh();
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
}
```

The dom is basically an

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
...
    <div *ngIf="user.fav">
               <i class="fa fa-star favorite-inline"></i>
    </div>
...
</div>
```

Comment: what does `this.usersService.favorite(id)` call do?

Comment: It does a http call to add a userid to the logged in users favorites array.

Comment: Use angular lifecycle hooks ngOnInit

Comment: This is done from a user click and after ngoninit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the users data is driven by a web service call, I would recommend binding it to the template via a Subject and using the `async` pipe that Angular provides.

That should update the template each time the Subject emits a change/new value. Using `take(1)` ensures that the `Observable` returned by the `geosearch` method completes to avoid memory leaks.

**component**:

```
class myComponent {
   usersSubject: Subject<UserInterface>;

   constructor(...) {
      ...
      this.usersSubject = new Subject();
      ...
   }

   refresh() {
     this.usersService.geosearch(this.usersService.user)
       .take(1)
       .subscribe(
           userData => {
              this.usersSubject.next(userData);
           }
       );
  }

}
```

**template**:

```
<div *ngIf="usersSubject | async as users>
    <div *ngFor="let user of users">
    ...
        <div *ngIf="user.fav">
                   <i class="fa fa-star favorite-inline"></i>
        </div>
    ...
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you correctly.

I suppose that `favorite` method returns an Observable or a Subject.
When you subscribe there are few events occurring:

1. onNext
2. onError
3. onComplete

basically it looks like this:

```
this.someService.someMethod()
  .subscribe(
    // onNext
    result => console.log(result),

    // onError
    error => console.log(error),

    // onComplete
    () => this.foo()
  );
```

For you code my guess it should look like this:

```
favoriteThisUser(id: string) {
  this.usersService.favorite(id).subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log('SUCCESS!!!', data);
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
    },
    () => {
      this.refresh();
    }
  );
}
```

After the data subscription is done the completed method is running. If there was an error the completed (or `() =>`) will not run.

Hope that helps